# Applying dynamic theme in vuejs

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js

I am trying to change theme dynamically in vueJs, I'll get color code from API, and I want to change theme according to that.

right now I've done like this.

in util.js

```
var ChangeTheme = {
    applyTheme_fn(color) {
        document.querySelector(".navbar .navbar-collapse").style.color = color
        ...
    }
} 

export default ChangeTheme
```

in home.vue

```
import ChangeTheme from '@/components/util.js'
....
methods: {
    someMethod() {
        let themeColor = data.response.themeColor // color code from API response
        ChangeTheme.applyTheme_fn(themeColor)
    }
}
```

This works at some places, but not in all places. If I write style in particular component it works there. but querySelector is not applying at all places.

is there any workaround for this?

Comment: Thats becoz any Dom manipulation commands like `querySelector` etc can fetch only the elements that are present on the DOM. So other components which are not visible on Dom won't be affected hence you are not able to see the change at that point of time visually

Comment: @Amaarrockz okay, is there any way to do this without querySelector?

Comment: Ya, you can have a global state for theme set in vuex store which you can access across all components. Therefore when the `theme` state changes, all the component will have the impact